# How can I add a class to a block by clicking on a button, hide another block and replace the text in the button?

Tags: vue.js

How can I add a class to a block by clicking on a button, hide another block and replace the text in the button?

I spent a lot of time not getting it done, help

```css
.box-table {
  display: none;
}

.box-table.active {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id=app>
  <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-box">
            <div class="box-img">btn-click-hide</div>
            <div class="box-table">btn-click-show add class active</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">show (hide)</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a script tag to write the vue code, use the createApp function to create an application instance, use ref in setup to define a responsive variable **show** to control the button display and then return it, and then you can use Mustache syntax to access the variable in HTML.

```html
<script>
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const show = ref(false)
    return {
      show
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Then, you can use v-if and v-else to determine which elements need to be displayed or not based on the value of **show**, and you can also use it for dynamic binding of classes. Similarly, you can use trinocular expressions in Mustache syntax to confirm the text displayed by the button.

```html
<div id=app>
  <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-box">
            <div class="box-img" v-if="!show">btn-click-hide</div>
            <div class="box-table" :class="{ active: show }" v-else>btn-click-show add class active</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" @click="show = !show">{{ show ? 'show' : 'hide'}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is all the code.

If you want to know more, please check the official website of Vue
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id=app>
  <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-box">
            <div class="box-img" v-if="!show">btn-click-hide</div>
            <div class="box-table" :class="{ active: show }" v-else>btn-click-show add class active</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" @click="show = !show">{{ show ? 'show' : 'hide'}}</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const show = ref(false)
    return {
      show
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create a variable to save state and function to toggle button, example:

```js
const isShowSomeThing = ref(false);
const textBtn = computed(() => {
   isShowSomeThing == false ? "Show" : "Hide";
})
function toggleShowSomething() {
   isShowSomeThing.value = !isShowSomeThing.value;
}
```

Then you use v-if, v-else to show that when click button with onclick event and text change when state change, example:

```html
<div id=app>
  <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrap-box">
            <div v-if="isShowSomeThing == false" >Image</div>
            <div v-else>Table</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" onclick="toggleShowSomeThing()">{{ textBtn }}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems fair it should work.

Comment: its basic and easy to understand.